# Java - Not accounting for final elements in linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

The object of the following method is to delete any number after the first in a linked-list that is greater than the one before it. And once that's deleted it also checks that number with the one previous - else continue.

Example list :

```
[1,2,3,4,5,0,0,1,2,1]
```

Would yield

```
[1,0,0]
```

Because (2 > 1 ) 2 removed, (3 > 1) 3 removed, (4 > 1) 4 removed, (5 > 1) 5 removed), (0 < 1) nothing happens (current list = [1,0], (0 == 0), nothing happens list = [1,0,0], (1 > 0) gets removed... ect

The code I have now leaves the last element tacked at the end so instead of [1,0,0] it reads [1,0,0,1]

Current code:

```
public void deleteLarger() {
    Node<T> current = head; 
    Node<T> previous = null;

    while(current != null) {
        if (previous != null){
            if (current.getValue().compareTo(previous.getValue()) > 0){
                remove(current.getValue());
            }
            if (current.getValue().compareTo(previous.getValue()) < 0){
                remove(previous.getValue());
            }
        }
        previous = current;
        current  = current.getNext(); 
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like it might be comparing it in the original list without the removals, maybe.. If you put a 3 instead of the 1 in the end, does it still get printed? Also, try debugging and watching the values you are comparing to better see what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void deleteLarger() {

    Node<T> current = head; 
    Node<T> previous = null;

    while(current != null) {
        if (previous != null && current.getValue().compareTo(previous.getValue()) > 0){
            Node<T> toremove = current;
            current = current.getNext(); 
            remove(toremove.getValue());  // or remove(toremove); ?
        } else {
            previous = current;
            current  = current.getNext(); 
        }
    }
}
```